# All site pages jumping at start in android

Tags: android, html

When I enter my site from Android tablet and phone, my site is looking fine then after a second all the pages are scaling to a smaller resolution like it is shrinking and after 2 more seconds the site is fine again.

I have this meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height">
```

Comment: Try this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: Don't use `>` before every line unless you are quoting information from somebody or some other site.